# Not able to add carousel_slider package in flutter application

Tags: flutter, carousel-slider

Running "flutter pub get" in carousel_slider...
Resolving dependencies...
Error on line 34, column 3 of pubspec.yaml: A package may not list itself as a dependency.
╷
34 │   carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
│   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
pub get failed

I tried changing the file name still the same error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be the alignment issue. Make sure the pubspec.yaml look like this:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
```